# Macintosh HD getting renamed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-silicon

Yesterday when I opened my MacBook Air M1 the Macintosh HD on the Desktop was renamed with some random name, Yes I renamed it back but, this is second time in past two months. Didn't find anything related to this issue.

Any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: Can you rule out that you accidentally renamed it yourself? What was the "random" name?

Comment: @KevinGrabher Nope i didn't renamed it, not even by accidentally. The recent random name was **[poiuytrewq**